# Selecting k sub-posets

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, np-hard, poset

I ran into the following algorithmic problem while experimenting with classification algorithms. Elements are classified into a polyhierarchy, what I understand to be a poset with a single root. I have to solve the following problem, which looks a lot like the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

I uploaded my Latex-ed problem description [here](http://dareios.com/k_sub_graph_cover.pdf).

Devising an approximation algorithm that satisfies 1 & 2 is quite easy, just start at the vertices of G and "walk up" or start at the root and "walk down". Say you start at the root, iteratively expand vertexes and then remove unnecessary vertices until you have at least k sub-lattices. The approximation bound depends on the number of children of a vertex, which is OK for my application.

Does anyone know if this problem has a proper name, or maybe the tree-version of the problem? I would be interested to find out if this problem is NP-hard, maybe someone has ideas for a good NP-hard problem to reduce or has a polynomial algorithm to solve the problem. If you have both collect [your million dollar price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). ;)

Comment: I don't understand.  If you choose S' = {r} where r is the root, then \sigma(r) = V.  Do you mean sigma(s) to be all the elements less than or equal to r and greater than or equal to s (where less and greater are the lattice partial order)?

Comment: @deinst That's why `k` is there: to make the problem more interesting :)  `S = {r}` is the solution for `k = 1`.

Comment: @dareios You might want to correct two minor mistakes in the problem statement.  1) The second last paragraph is not true in general, depends on the choice of `G` (unless I'm missing something, if `G` contains two children and nothing more, then `S = G` is a solution with `l = k = 2`.  2) In the third last paragraph, you probably mean: "[...] we still want to keep **2**."

Comment: Do you have an actual lattice or just a DAG with a single source vertex?

Comment: More precisely, do you have binary meets and/or joins?

Comment: @Bolo So property 3 should state that there is no S' such that k <= |S'| < l

Comment: @Bolo You are right, I added a choice for G to the example and corrected the misplaced reference.

@deinst I think the >= k is actually missing for the definition to be correct, I added that.

Comment: @throwawayacct I only have a root node ("largest" vertex), not a single "smallest" vertex. So I guess the structure has binary joins but no binary meets (and only learned these terms from the wiki article ;)) So I guess I have a partially ordered set with binary joins, not a lattice. Correct?

Comment: After thinking about it some more, the structure does not even have binary meets (then it would be a semilattice), because it is possible that two children a and b each have two direct parents x and y. This means the supremum is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DAG version is hard by (drum roll) a reduction from set cover. Set k = 2 and do the obvious: condition (2) prevents us from taking the root. (Note that (3) doesn't actually imply (2) because of the lower bound k.)

The tree version is a special case of the series-parallel poset version, which can be solved exactly in polynomial time. Here's a recursive formula that gives a polynomial p(x) where the coefficient of x<sup>n</sup> is the number of covers of cardinality n.

Single vertex to be covered: p(x) = x.

Other vertex: p(x) = 1 + x.

Parallel composition, where q and r are the polynomials for the two posets: q(x) r(x).

Series composition, where q is the polynomial for the top poset and r, for the bottom: If the top poset contains no vertices to be covered, then p(x) = (q(x) - 1) + r(x); otherwise, p(x) = q(x).

Comment: Good observation with (3) does not imply (2), I totally missed that. Changed in the problem statement. For the rest I guess I need one night of sleep first, thank you for your answer!

Comment: The reduction is easy indeed, don't know why I couldn't do it yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: For the tree-version recursion formula: If I have a single vertex to be covered, I have p(x)=x as you say, as there is only one cover. For no vertexes to be covered we should have p(x)=1 (as the cover is empty). I don't understand when the "Other vertex: p(x)=1+x" polynomial is applied. Also, I don't understand when the "top poset contains no vertices" (to be covered) applies: The top poset will always contain the other posets so if it doesn't contain vertexes to be covered, the other posets won't either. Maybe the >= k restriction on the minimum property comes into play here?

Comment: It's 1 + x because you didn't demand that each vertex in the cover actually cover anything, so you have a choice of whether to include it. If the (sub-)tree root has to be covered, then you have to put it in and leave all of its proper descendants out.